# How do I apply schema with nullable = false to json reading

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to write some test cases using json files for dataframes (whereas production would be parquet). I'm using spark-testing-base framework and I'm running into a snag when asserting data frames equal each other due to schema mismatches where the json schema always has nullable = true.

I'd like to be able to apply a schema with nullable = false to the json read.

I've written a small test case:

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StructField, StructType}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class TestJSON extends FunSuite with DataFrameSuiteBase {

  val expectedSchema = StructType(
    List(StructField("a", IntegerType, nullable = false),
         StructField("b", IntegerType, nullable = true))
  )
  test("testJSON") {
    val readJson =
      spark.read.schema(expectedSchema).json("src/test/resources/test.json")

    assert(readJson.schema == expectedSchema)

  }
}
```

And have a small test.json file of:

`{"a": 1, "b": 2}
{"a": 1}`

This returns an assertion failure of

> StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,true),
>   StructField(b,IntegerType,true)) did not equal
>   StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,false),
>   StructField(b,IntegerType,true)) ScalaTestFailureLocation:
>   TestJSON$$anonfun$1 at (TestJSON.scala:15) Expected
>   :StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,false),
>   StructField(b,IntegerType,true)) Actual
>   :StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,true),
>   StructField(b,IntegerType,true))

Am I applying the schema the correct way?
I'm using spark 2.2, scala 2.11.8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a workaround, where rather than reading the json directly from the file, read it using RDD then it applies the schema. Below is code:

```
val expectedSchema = StructType(
    List(StructField("a", IntegerType, nullable = false),
         StructField("b", IntegerType, nullable = true))
  )


  test("testJSON") {
    val jsonRdd =spark.sparkContext.textFile("src/test/resources/test.json")
    //val readJson =sparksession.read.schema(expectedSchema).json("src/test/resources/test.json")
    val readJson = spark.read.schema(expectedSchema).json(jsonRdd)
    readJson.printSchema()
    assert(readJson.schema == expectedSchema)

  }
```

The test case passes and the print schema result is :

```
root
 |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
```

There is JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10848 with apache Spark for this issue, which they say is not a problem and said that:

> This should be resolved in the latest file format refactoring in Spark 2.0. Please reopen it if you still hit the problem. Thanks!

If you are getting the error you can open the JIRA again.
I tested in spark 2.1.0, and still see the same issue

Comment: I see you've also commented on this issue, should I comment as well and point to this page?

Comment: Yes please you can. I don't see the option of reopening the JIRA. If you have the option you can reopen it.

Comment: Still an issue in Spark 3.0.1 and I see the Spark JIRA issue is marked as resolved. Doesn't make sense that some elements of the schema (in this case nullability) is dropped despite providing explicit user schema. Perhaps it should be reopened?

Answer (score 2):

The workAround aboves ensures there is a correct schema, but null values are set to default ones. In my case when an Int does not exist in the json String it is set to 0.