# How can I validate Json schema in spark 2.X?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Using *Spark* streaming (written in **Scala**) to read messages from Kafka.
The messages are all Strings in Json format.

Defining the expected schema in a local variable `expectedSchema`
then parsing the Strings in the RDD to Json

```
spark.sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rdd.toDS())
```

**The problem:** Spark will process all the records/rows as long as it has some fields that I try to read, even if the actual Json format (i.e schema) of the input row (String) doesn't match my `expectedSchema`.

Assume expected schema looks like this (in Json): `{"a": 1,"b": 2, "c": 3}`
and input row looks like this:  `{"a": 1, "c": 3}`
Spark will process the input without failing.

I tried using the solution described here: [How do I apply schema with nullable = false to json reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443483/how-do-i-apply-schema-with-nullable-false-to-json-reading)

but `assert(readJson.schema == expectedSchema)` never fails, even when I deliberately send input rows with wrong Json schema.

1. Is there a way for me to verify that the actual schema of a given input row, matches my expected schema?
2. Is there a way for me to insert a null value to "fill" fields missing from "corrupt" schema row?

Comment: Spark does #2 automatically. If you provide the schema while reading and a field is missing in one of the rows, it'll populate that column as null automatically.

Comment: @philantrovert is there a way for me to know for which fields it does it, and to control the "fill" value?

Comment: I'm not aware of any method that does it iteratively on a row-to-row basis. However you can use `df.na.fill` to replace nul values after the dataframe has been created.

Comment: @philantrovert what do you mean "after the DataFrame has been created"?  Like after `df = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rdd.toDS())`  or after I preform some action which forces the data to the driver?

Comment: Maybe this blog post helps, there is a library that allows you to do step 1 https://medium.com/@mrpowers/validating-spark-dataframe-schemas-28d2b3c69d2a . Otherwise, what @philantrovert means is that after you read the schema, spark automatically puts 'null' when a field is missing. If you want to control it, just after applying the scema do what he suggested.