# Apache Spark Scala - Loading data from a CSV file with a specified schema does not respect nullability constraints

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to load a CSV file into a Spark DataFrame using scala and I have a problem enforcing the nullability constraint. This should be quite simillar to the issue with reading JSON files described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443483/how-do-i-apply-schema-with-nullable-false-to-json-reading) and I wonder if someone has a simillar solution or any suggestion for CSV files.

The snippets below are tested using spark-shell with spark version 3.4

The CSV file contents at '/data/persons.csv' are :

```
1,John,1990-01-01
2,Peter,2000-01-02
3,Laura,1991-01-03
4,Maria,2001-01-04
```

The code that loads the above into a DataFrame is as follows:

1. Schema Definition

```
val personSchema =  StructType(Seq(
  StructField("id",IntegerType,nullable=false), // NOT NULL
  StructField("name",StringType),
  StructField("dob",DateType)
))
```

2. Code that loads the CSV into the DataFrame

```
val personDF = spark.read.
  schema(personSchema).
  option("header","false").
  option("inferSchema", "false").
  csv("/data/persons.csv")
```

Note: I have attempted to use .format("csv") and .load("/data/persons.csv") instead of .csv("/data/persons.csv") and I have the same behavior.

The DataFrame is loaded successfully and `personDF.show` returns the following:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id| name|       dob|
+---+-----+----------+
|  1| John|1990-01-01|
|  2|Peter|2000-01-02|
|  3|Laura|1991-01-03|
|  4|Maria|2001-01-04|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Then we can see the not null constraint is not enforced in the DataFrame `personDF.printSchema` returns

```
scala> personDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: date (nullable = true)
```

The proposed solution from the JSON article was:

```
   val jsonRdd =spark.sparkContext.textFile("src/test/resources/test.json")
    //val readJson =sparksession.read.schema(expectedSchema).json("src/test/resources/test.json")
    val readJson = spark.read.schema(expectedSchema).json(jsonRdd)
    readJson.printSchema()
```

I have attempted to "adapt" it to my csv case below without success :

```
val csvRdd =spark.sparkContext.textFile("/data/persons.csv")
val personDF = spark.read.schema(personSchema).csv(csvRdd)
```

leads to:

```
scala> val personDF = spark.read.schema(personSchema).csv(csvRdd)
<console>:48: error: overloaded method value csv with alternatives:
  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (csvDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String])
       val personDF = spark.read.schema(personSchema).csv(csvRdd)
```

The suggestion from pasha701 for spark 3.4.1 seems to workl, extract form spark-shell:

```
scala> val initial = spark.read.option("header", "false").schema(personSchema).csv("/data/persons.csv")
initial: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val result = spark.createDataFrame(initial.rdd, personSchema)
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> result.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: date (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Such solution works in Spark 3.1.2:**

CSV file can be read as text file into DataSet of Strings, and converted to DataFrame:

```
val ds = spark.read.textFile("/data/persons.csv").toDF().as[String]
val result = spark.read.schema(personSchema)
  .option("inferSchema","false")
  .option("header","false")
  .csv(ds)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: date (nullable = true)
```

**For Spark 3.4.1:**

Schema can be assigned after reading, to RDD:

```
val initial = spark.read
  .option("header", "false")
  .schema(personSchema)
  .csv("/data/persons.csv")
val result = spark.createDataFrame(initial.rdd, personSchema)
```

Comment: Does not work for me see my updated question above

Comment: Works fine in Spark 3.1.2, for 3.4 other approach added.